# Iterate over multiple lists (with no performance fall)

Tags: python, performance, list

I'm writing a game and in *while True:* loop I have a code repainting game state.

I have few lists of objects of different kinds (spaceships, beams, stars) - all to improve performance.

And I need to paint them all. I could do:

```
for spaceship in spaceships:
    screen.blit(spaceship.image, (spaceship.x, spaceship.y))
for beam in beams:
    screen.blit(beam.image, (beam.x, beam.y))
...
```

but I feel it's somehow against the DRY principle. And I just feel it can be done better.

What I need is a construction like this:

```
for actor in spaceships + beams + stars:
    actor.move()
    screen.blit(actor.image, (actor.x, actor.y))
```

but a one, which wouldn't join them all (nor do anything which would decrease the performance). Your ideas?

Answer (score 6):

Use [`chain`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) from the `itertools` module:

```
from itertools import chain
for actor in chain(spaceships, beams, stars):
    actor.move()
    screen.blit(actor.image, (actor.x, actor.y))
```

From the docs:

> Make an iterator that returns elements from the first iterable until
>   it is exhausted, then proceeds to the next iterable, until all of the
>   iterables are exhausted. Used for treating consecutive sequences as a
>   single sequence.

`chain` uses lazy evaluation (e.g. no intermediate lists are created), so there will not be any performance drop.